# Jquery load(): body class not retrieved

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When I use jquery's `.load()` function to load the next pages body it does not retrieve the class of the body of that page. Is there a way to achieve this?

Thank you :)

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if(navigator.standalone){
        $('a').live("click", function (e) {
            var link = $(this).attr('href');
            if ($(this).hasClass('noeffect')){
            }
        else {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("body").load(link);
            };
        });
    }
    else {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0.9);
    }
});
```

Comment: Need more context of what you are doing. What are you binding a load event handler to? Where is a body of any page being loaded from/to? If you can post your pertinent HTML and JavaScript that is helpful.

Comment: Hi! Please, provide some code because your question is very ambiguous!

Comment: You mean something like `.load().find('body').attr('class')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so your putting a body inside a body?  not sure that'll work as expected!

some html would be helpful, but i'm guessing that is what the problem is.

in the pages that you are loading into your body, put them inside a div instead of a body tag.  that should avoid the body inside a body problem.

---

Edit:

what you could do is do a regular ajax call to get your new html.  then remove your current body,  and append the stuff you get back from the ajax call to your html.   I've never tried something like that, but if you can't change the html that your getting back, it's probably the best thing to try.

Comment: i can't, it's existing html :p. not mine.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if(navigator.standalone){
        $('a').live("click", function (e) {
            var link = $(this).attr('href');
            if ($(this).hasClass('noeffect')){}
            else {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.get(link, null, function(result) {
                     $("body").replaceWith(result);
                });                    
            });
        }
    else {window.scrollTo(0, 0.9);}
});
```

This assumes that the response only contains the body and it's contents. If it includes the html you might want `$("html").replaceWith(result)`

Comment: does not work since the body get's replaced (so it's gone afterwards)

Answer (score 0):

I find a pretty easy solution to get the body element of ajax response. The idea is:

1. Turn the BODY tag of response into a DIV
2. Wrap the DIV with a BODY

   ```
   $.get(url)
     .success(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
       var data = data.replace('<body', '<body><div id="body"').replace('</body>', '</div></body>');
       var body = $(data).filter('#body');
       // feel free the get HTML, class, attributes, etc. of ajax response BODY
     });
   ```

It works in Chrome, so I believe in works in other browser as well.